# CSS Element Selector Within Pre-existing CSS block

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this

```
.main-content {color: red; font-size: 10px;}
.main-content > h1 {font-size: 25px;}
```

I don't know if this is actually a thing, but I vaguely remember seeing this done more elegantly within the first css block, but I can't seem to figure out how it works, or if I even remember it correctly.

For example (*this doesn't actually work but it should explain what I am trying to accomplish*)

```
.main-content {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  > h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is called LESS. But you would need a preprocessor to turn into legit CSS

Comment: @Gerard I'm not familiar with preprocessors? Could you explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or similar css preprocessors.

Comment: Preprocessor not library